# How can I use the results from 1 column as a part of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Maybe I just don't know how to properly search this out, or if this technique has come kind of name, but I think what I'm trying to do must be relatively simple, I've just never done it before.

```
select 
sum(miles) as totalMiles
,sum(events) as events
,round(sum(events)/(sum(miles)/1000),1) as events_per1k
from ...
```

so, you can see that I've got totalMiles and events already in place, and then have to sum them AGAIN to calculate the 3rd columns value.

Is there a way I could get the 3rd columns value without having to `sum(miles)` and `sum(events)` again?
something like this?

```
select 
sum(miles) as totalMiles
,sum(events) as events
,round((val:col2)/((val:col1)/1000),1) as events_per1k
from ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference them directly in the SELECT, but you could wrap them in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
   ROUND( i.events / (i.totalMiles / 1000), 1) as events_perlk
FROM (
   SELECT 
      sum(miles)  as totalMiles,
      sum(events) as events
   FROM 
   ...
) i;
```

There may be a more performant solution than this, but this is simple and will do the job.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b086d8/2 (guessing at your schema)

Comment: This is a very good answer, I didn't think to use a subquery, but this doesn't affect the overall performance, which is what I'm going for.
2.5M rows in this query.
I would upvote if I could!

Maybe it does - it took .2 seconds off the time (using SQL_NO_CACHE to avoid cache messing with me.)